# javascript function to color using color array and for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have created a function to create some html elements from a JSON object. I have also created an array of 3 different colors and want to loop through the array, using each color at a time to color part of a sentence formed by the html elements.
There are 2 roles in this particular object (ie. singleJSONObj.roles.length is equal to 2). I am trying to get it to print the first html element as "DarkSalmon" and then the next one as "ForestGreen" as it loops. It is, however, printing both role names with "Darksalmon". Please see my code below. What am I missing?

```
function createHtmlElementsforRoleNumbers (singleJSONObj, XML)
{

// result to be returned
    var finalXML;

    var colorArr = ["DarkSalmon", "ForestGreen", "Brown"]

// block of html elements to be created
    var htmlforRoleNumbers = "";

    for ( var i=0; i< singleJSONObj.roles.length; i++)
    {
        // each time creating one html element.
        // e.g. If length above is 2, create 2 h4 elements.
        htmlforRoleNumbers = htmlforRoleNumbers +
            "<h4><br> - a(n) <font color='" + colorArr[i] + "'>" +
                singleJSONObj.roles[i].name +
            "</font><br></h4>";

    }
    finalXML =  String(XML).replace(/Role_numbers/g,htmlforRoleNumbers)

    // output
    return finalXML;
}
```

Comment: This code looks valid for me. Is it cycling through `singleJSONObj.roles[i].name` as expected or is it printing the `name` of 1st index twice as well?

Comment: Your JavaScript works as expected. Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/d5fsr6cu/